# condition number with component-wise norm for the sample variance any help is appreciated! :)

Tags: matrices, algorithms, numerical-methods

I'm looking through some notes and came across the following two statements in the notes where the author states it can be shown that one leads to the next. I've tried to show this using the definition of sample variance mean but can't see anyway through it. Any and all help is appreciated! thanks for your time!

[image: Q1]

[image]